# Why there is no output in kafka topic when I use wirteStream() in spark-streaming? version:spark2.4.3

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I want to use the kafka sink in the spark-streaming documentation to write my data to kafka, but why is there no output in the kafka topic while has the query log?

I am using the java code mentioned in the documentation, the version of the spark is 2.4.3

```java
query = result
        .writeStream()
        .outputMode(outputmode)
        .format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaMap.get("kafka.bootstrap.servers").toString())
        .option("topic", kafkaMap.get("topic").toString())
        .option("checkpointLocation", "path/to/HDFS/dir")
        .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(triggerTime))
        .start();
```

The input source is socket. In other test cases, the input works well. And the data is just string

I don't know why there is no output in the kafka topic when I start the consumer.
When I use console sink, the output like this :
[image]